# How to parse string from Serial monitor in Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, serial-port, at-command

My code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial1.write("AT+DTTX\n");
  delay(5000);
  while (Serial1.available()) {
    String txtMsg = Serial1.readString();
    Serial.println(txtMsg);
  }  
}
```

Serial monitor:

> 1
>
> AT+DTTX OK
>
> Radio Tx Done RadioTxDelayDone Radio Rx Done Len:2 RSSI:-93 SNR:33
>
> 2
>
> AT+DTTX OK
>
> Radio Tx Done RadioTxDelayDone Radio Rx Done Len:2 RSSI:-90 SNR:32
>
> 3 AT+DTTX OK
>
> Radio Tx Done RadioTxDelayDone Radio Rx Done Len:2 RSSI:-92 SNR:22

How to get RSSI and SNR from Serial monitor?

I want results like:

1 RSSI:-93 SNR:33

2 RSSI:-90 SNR:32

3 RSSI:-92 SNR:22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  char *tmp = strstr (strtoparse, "RRSI");
```

Tmp points to it or is NULL.

Then you can do whatever you want with it. I assume the format you provided us. If it is not parsing may be quite complicated